# lock a line for editing in a textbox in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have a textbox on a userform. When the userform displays, the textbox opens with some 
default value.

I want it to be such that the Line1 (or some words) of the default message is displayed in grey color and must be locked for editing. Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean with "locked for editing"? The user can't delete the default message but add more text?

Comment: Cant delete, cant add. Actually I want the first line to be locked for editing. I dont think its possible.

Comment: I have suggested an alternative as well. You might have to refresh the page.

Comment: Do you want me to show how the alternative works?

Comment: No. Thanks. Smart answer.

Comment: Oop's I just saw your comment. I already updated the answer :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Locking the TextBox for Editing?

**Yes.** it is possible.

Just set the `.Locked` Property to `True`

> Locking/Coloring just the first line or part of a text in textBox?

**No**. It is not possible in VBA. For partial coloring, you may want to use `RichTextBox` in lieu of `TextBox` but then again you will not be able to partially lock the control.

**Edit**

**Alternative**: Since the first line of text contains text that shouldn't be edited then why not show that info in a `ToolTip` using the `.ControlTipText` property of the `TextBox` or say a `Label` which displays when you hover the mouse on top of the `TextBox`?

For example (Using the `.ControlTipText` property)

```
Option Explicit

'~~> This is what goes in the tooltip. Amend as applicable.
Const sMsg As String = "Hello World! This is an example of tooltip text"

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim sSample As String
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To 10
        sSample = sSample & "Blah Blah" & i & vbNewLine
    Next i

    TextBox1.Text = sSample

    '~~> Set to starting point
    TextBox1.SelStart = 0
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, _
                               ByVal Shift As Integer, _
                               ByVal X As Single, _
                               ByVal Y As Single)
    TextBox1.ControlTipText = sMsg
End Sub
```

And now when you hover the text on top of the TextBox, you will be shown the `ToolTip`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is more a workaround than a solution, but it works perfect (atleast on my computer).

```
Const defaultLine As String = "YourText" & vbcrlf

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    Static oldValue As String

    'set oldValue if empty
    If oldValue = "" Then
        oldValue = defaultLine
    End If

    'disable the change of the first line
    If Left(TextBox1.Value, Len(defaultLine)) <> defaultLine Then
        TextBox1.Value = oldValue
    Else
        oldValue = TextBox1.Value
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    TextBox1.Value = defaultLine
End Sub
```